# How to move an element to its next sibling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to grab an element and move it to its next sibling while at the same time adding attributes to that next sibling. How do I do that in jQuery?

Specifically, I want to move the "span" inside the "a" tags below, and add an `"data-toggle='tooltip'"` and `'title="SOMETHING HERE"'` attributes to that "a" tag.

Thus this:

```
<td>
  <span>Total partners</span>
  <a id="answer_view_2_list_row_7"></a>
</td>
```

would become this:

```
<td>
  <a id='answer_view_2_list_row_7' data-toggle='tooltip' title='SOMETHING HERE'>
    <span>Total partners</span>
  </a>
</td>
```

Any help appreciated. I'm learning jQuery but this one is beyond me.

Comment: this one is beyond you. Have you tried?

Comment: should this happen on click of something or.. !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('td a').append(function () {
    return $(this).parent().find('span')
}).data('toggle', 'tooltip').attr('title', 'SOMETHING HERE')
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/55mce3Lg/)**

Note that you won't see the data attribute in the source as it's stored internally.

Comment: This worked brilliantly, thanks. The function solved the problem that was stumping me: how to ensure I was appending the span to the sibling closure and not some other "a" closure elsewhere on the page, as noted by Barmar below.

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like:

```
// Append to `a` tag.
$('span').appendTo('a');
// Add attributes.
$('a').attr({
    'data-toggle':'tooltip',
    'title':'SOMETHING HERE'
});
```

Or better yet:

```
$('span').each(function() {
    $(this).next().attr({
        'data-toggle':'tooltip',
        'title':'SOMETHING HERE'
    });
    $(this).appendTo($(this).next());
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gub5d6tc/)

Comment: Shouldn't you use some DOM traversal functions so you append it to the next sibling, not some other random `a` element on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td > a').attr({
    'data-toggle': 'tooltip',
    'title': 'something here'
}).append($('td > span'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
$('myelement').each(function() { $(this).appendTo($(this).next()); });
```

Comment: It should be `appendTo`, not `insertAfter`.

Comment: No, that will put the `span` after the anchor, not inside it.

Comment: @Barmar Can you give me better explanation about your comment. I have seen this: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/what-is-the-difference-between-append-and-insertafter

Comment: it will do `<a>...</a><span>...</span>` instead of `<a><span>...</span></a>`.

Comment: @Barmar So, is it wrong? http://www.sitekickr.com/snippets/jquery/move-element-down-one-after-it-s-next-sibling I had also used this a month ago.

Comment: That works for siblings. But `<a>` is supposed to go _around_ something.

Comment: Look at the HTML in the question. He wants to move the span **inside** the `a`, not **after** it.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I said in my first comment.